# Factoring out a weight in a summation

Tags: database-design, math

I have a summation as follows:

```
H(t+1) = H(t) + K*(a-1)
```

And a database table that updates the values of H at every increment of t. I'd like to be able to later change the value of K (for tweaking purposes) but I'm not sure how to store the data in a way that will allow me to do that. If I store just the latest value of H, K is baked into the values and can't be retrieved. The alternative is to store the values at every t as a separate row but that might lead to a lot of data. Is there a way to factor out K which will allow me to recompute H for all t increments?

Comment: I see that as a recursive definition H(t) and not a summation. Is there a summation definition of the equation?

Comment: What columns does the table have? `t, a, H` ?

Comment: I'm actually trying to factor out the rating equation in the ELO ranking system so that I can adjust the K factor after the fact.